# paypal re-occurring payments

Tags: c#, paypal

When you have re-occurring payments setup with paypal with your customers/subscribers, is it possible to get a list of all subscribers from paypall's API?

If yes, what does it return, transactionIDs or user emails or?

I basically want a way to update my database with members who have active subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_TransactionSearch

May be of use?

Returns time/date, customer email, customer name, transaction ID, gross amount charged, fees, net amount.